# Calling methods from task in Cakefile

Tags: coffeescript, cakefile

I'm setting up a Cakefile that will compile and minify my CoffeeScript and minify my Vanilla libs.

I created different tasks for each case (whether it was a coffee file or not) but I want to combine them into one task.

The problem I'm having is calling a method from the task; I can call a method with no problem under some circumstances, but otherwise I receive

```
    TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

The object I'm working on looks like

```
source = 
  libs: [
    'lib/jquery-1.7.1.min.js'
    'lib/backbone.js'
    'lib/underscore.js'
  ]
  coffees: [
    'app/800cart.coffee'
    'app/models/coffee/cart.coffee'
    'app/models/coffee/contact.coffee'
  ]
```

And Im wanting to do this, and I get the error

```
 task 'build', 'Concat, compile, and minify files', ->
    for fileType, files of source
        concatinate files

    concatinate = (files) ->
      console.log 'concatinating'
```

The part that I'm really confused by is if I call the method with a condition it runs fine

```
 task 'build', 'Concat, compile, and minify files', ->
    for fileType, files of source
        concatinate files if fileType is 'coffees'

    concatinate = (files) ->
      console.log 'concatinating'
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to call `concatinate` before you define `concatinate` with the line `concatinate =`. Just move up the declaration, or better yet, move it outside of the task definition.

You're probably used to JavaScript's `function concatinate` syntax, which automatically moves the function to the top of the scope. CoffeeScript compiles to the `concatinate = function` syntax instead, mainly because the `function cocatinate` syntax behaves inconsistently across different JS runtimes (particularly IE). So, CoffeeScript functions simply obey ordinary variable assignment rules.